# Outlook plugin - Fetch emails with specific message ids

Tags: vba, outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am writing a plugin for Outlook, where I need to fetch only few emails based on some back end Logic.

I have stored those email Message Unique Ids in my DB. And on click of plugin Icon, I wish to load only those Emails to load in my Inbox.

Example, the logic is same as how we click on particular folder like sent items or unread items, it refreshes the Inbox with only the respective emails.

I have created a plugin icon following the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial

Using NodeJS for coding. Can you please give a pointer, how do we load emails in Inbox? or if we can load only specific emails in Inbox?

Comment: Could you clarify what your use case is here? It looks like you just want to fetch the contents of a given message id, which you can do through [graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message), but I don't follow how the add-in factors here.

Comment: On click of a plugin Icon, need to fetch few emails (based on unique message id).

Comment: Have updated the question. Please check if it is clear now

Comment: Outlook add-ins have a lot of restrictions.  You can't generally modify things outside of your sandboxed area, unless you are making server-side changes that the view listens to.  You can't tell the Inbox to only show the messages that you want to show.  You would have to create your own 'view', maybe in a dialog window (displayDialogAsync), to show the items, and maybe you could launch them natively using displayMessageForm.

Comment: It is not possible to alter the view of the Inbox via the Office.JS interface. As others have suggested, you could either display those e-mails in a task pane, or dialog. You can even provide functionality to open those e-mails via displayMessageForm. You could also move / copy those items to another folder via Graph/Rest/EWS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if you're attempting to use the Outlook's inbox display module to show the items you're refreshing. You will have to open a dialog / or a new browser tab to show the custom list of items - which I think is not good user experience. As Brian called out, office-js add-ins are quite restricted.